# Problems to import csv-file into mySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, etl

I'm trying to import a large csv-file which is tab-seperated (\t).

**My steps to achieve this:**

1. Upload the csv-file
2. Create a new table in my database (filename without .csv)
3. Because of the size of the file, split it into batches
4. Send the batches to my database

The table will be created. But it is empty and I don't know why. Thank you for your help.

**upload.php**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
//Declaration of function that will insert data into database
 function senddata(filename, table){
        var file = filename;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "senddata.php",
            data: {file: file, table: table},
            async: true,
            success: function(html){
                //$("#result").html(html);
            }
        })
        }
 </script>
<?php
$csv = array();
$batchsize = 1000; //split huge CSV file by 1,000
$fileName = $_FILES['csv']['name'];
$table = basename($fileName, ".csv");
$table = strval( $table);
 echo "<script> console.log('File & Table-Name: $table') </script>";

// sql to create table
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$DB_HOST = "XXXX"; 
$DB_NAME = "XXXX"; 
$DB_USER = "XXXX"; 
$DB_PASS = "XXXX"; 


$conn = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($conn->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $conn->connect_error . ']');
};
    $query = "SELECT ID FROM " . $table; // that should be id and not ID
    //$result = mysql_query($mysql_connexn, $query); 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);


if(empty($result)) {
    echo "<script> console.log('Table: $table created!') </script>";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$table` (
      id  VARCHAR(8),
      preferred_term  VARCHAR(217),
      synonyms  VARCHAR(217),
      PRIMARY KEY(synonyms)
    )");
    }
    else {
        echo "<script> console.log('Table: $table already exists!') </script>";
    } // else

if($_FILES['csv']['error'] == 0){
    $name = $_FILES['csv']['name'];

    $tmp = explode('.', $_FILES['csv']['name']);
    $endTmp = end($tmp);
    $ext = strtolower($endTmp);
    $tmpName = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];
    if($ext === 'csv'){ //check if uploaded file is of CSV format
        if(($handle = fopen($tmpName, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
            set_time_limit(0);
            $row = 0;
            while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, $batchsize, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
                //echo "<script>console.log($data) </script>";
                $col_count = count($data);
                //splitting of CSV file :
                if ($row % $batchsize == 0):
                    $file = fopen("chunks$row.csv","w");
                endif;
                $csv[$row]['col1'] = $data[0];
                $csv[$row]['col2'] = $data[1];
                $csv[$row]['col3'] = $data[2];
                $id = $data[0];
                $preferred_term = $data[1];
                $synonyms = $data[2];
                $json = "'$id', '$preferred_term', '$synonyms'";
                fwrite($file,$json.PHP_EOL);
                //sending the splitted CSV files, batch by batch...
                if ($row % $batchsize == 0):
                    //echo "<script> console.log('chunks$row.csv', '$table'); </script>";
                    echo "<script> senddata('chunks$row.csv', '$table'); </script>";

                endif;
                $row++;
            }
            fclose($file);
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Only CSV files are allowed.";
    }
    //alert once done.
    echo "<script> console.log('CSV File imported!') </script>";
}
?>
```

**senddata.php**

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

$data = $_POST['file'];
$table = $_POST['table'];
$handle = fopen($data, "r");
    
if ($handle) {
    $counter = 0;
    //instead of executing query one by one,
    //prepare 1 SQL query that will insert all values from the batch
    $sql ="INSERT INTO `$table`(id,preferred_term,synonyms) VALUES ";
    while (($line = fgets($handle, "\t")) !== false) {
      $sql .= "($line),";
      $counter++;
    }
    $sql = substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql) - 1);
     if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    } else {
     }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
}
//unlink CSV file once already imported to DB to clear directory
unlink($data);
?>
```

Comment: take a look at bulk inserts https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html , splitting the files, is probably a good idea , which i would only use in my secnd attempt if the drect handöling by mysql fails

Comment: I don't think you're using [$batchsize](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fgetcsv.asp) correctly.  I agree with  nbk: *don't* try splitting the files prematurely.  I also agree with Lounis: LOAD DATA might be a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `LOAD DATA` mysql function, it's extremely fast and it was developed for this purpose (heavy file loading).

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Example :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' 
INTO TABLE my_table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

So you don't need to loop over each elements, you only configure delimiter, end of line character, etc.

It's more efficient than to do it with php and a big function.

Comment: I use mySQL Version 5.7. Isn't it for Version 8.0?

Comment: it's ok for mysql 5.7.